# GDI - How to create and fill bitmap?

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, gdi+, gdi

Someone can give me short explanation how to create bitmap runtime using GDI/GDI+ and to fill it with color ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `CreateBitmap`, `CreateCompatibleBitmap` or `CreateDIBSection` (in case you want access to raw underlying data bits)
2. `CreateCompatibleDC`
3. `SelectObject` the bitmap into created device context
4. `FillRect` or friends on the device context, and the painting takes place on your selected bitmap (there are options there: standard brushes for black and white, having RGB on hands instead of creating a brush you can do `SetBkColor` + `ExtTextOut` with an empty string and `ETO_OPAQUE` and the rectangle will be filled)
5. `SelectObject` back
6. The bitmap remains to hold the painting
7. Release the resources

Still it has something to do with "entire screen" in the title, and you need explain what you want there.

Comment: Instead of `CreateBitmap`, `CreateCompatibleBitmap` given a window DC will avoid lot of headache about forma conversions.

Also, the bitmap's compatible DC should be deleted before the end.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Query screen size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx)
2. Create your drawable (or just manipulate the graphics object in your paint handler)
3. [Fill it with color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984364%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

:)