# Initialize Gdiplus bitmap with color

Tags: bitmap, gdi+

I intend to draw in the bitmap pBmp. That part works ok. I want to initialize this bitmap with a (background) color. 
This is my workaround to accomplish it:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Gdiplus.h>

#define BITMAPX 1000
#define BITMAPY 600

Gdiplus::Bitmap *pBmp;
Gdiplus::Graphics *pGraph;

void init()
{
    pBmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(BITMAPX, BITMAPY, PixelFormat24bppRGB);  // Uninitialized bitmap
    pGraph = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(pBmp);                            // Uninitialized graphics object
    pGraph->Clear(Color::Snow);                                 // Set background color and use as a template 
    delete pBmp;                                                // Free for reuse
    pBmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(BITMAPX, BITMAPY, pGraph);               // Create bitmap with background color
}
```

There must be a better way with Palette or the like but after googling for a while I couldn't find a concise example to acheive that.
Anyone got a one-liner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GDI - How to create and fill bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037228/gdi-how-to-create-and-fill-bitmap)

Comment: The question is GDI+, the duplicate link is for GDI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PixelFormat24bppRGB` is 24-bit bitmap with no alpha channel. Use `PixelFormat32bppARGB` for 32-bit bitmap with alpha channel.

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap bmp(100, 100, Gdiplus::PixelFormat32bppARGB);
```

Fill with transparent background:

```
Gdiplus::Graphics *mem = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(&bmp);
Gdiplus::SolidBrush brush_tr(Gdiplus::Color::Transparent);
mem->FillRectangle(&brush_tr, 0,0,100,100);
```

This should appear as blank if printed on `HDC` device context

```
Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);
g.DrawImage(&bmp, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Just what I wanted! The reason I didn't try this first what my misconception that FromImage() created a copy while it in fact creates a pointer to the same image memory.